# Django Pass Input to URL

Tags: python, django

I want to make a search field in django.
I have a database with books and want, that the user can write e.g. "3" in a field and than the URL should look like this: `www.url.com/search/3` 3 is the id

How can I do that?

btw. I already have this: `www.url.com/book/3` but I want, that the user writes it in a input field :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple Search out of a `ListView`:

```
# see search results based on user query

class SearchQuestionView(ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'learn/search_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'questions'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', '')
        topic = self.request.GET.get('topic', '')
        object_list = Question.objects.filter(
                Q(question_text__icontains=query))
        if topic:
            object_list = object_list.filter(topic__name__icontains=topic)
        return object_list
```

You can add additional filters in the same way you added the `topic` filter.

Then, your form to search this could look like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'search-results' %}" method="GET">   
     <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Question Text" aria-label="Search">
     <input name="topic" type="text" placeholder="Topic" aria-label="Search">
     <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

This is a cool way to get introduced to the incredibly powerful `__` for Django querysets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/).